# How to stop 'window.showModalDialog' opening second window?

Tags: popup, showmodaldialog

In Microsoft's documentation I can't find the answer to my question on how to disable this feature.

The setup is that I have a browser open, that invokes the `window.showModalDialog`. After the user enters input in the popup window and submits a new window is opened from the pop-up.

I do not want the results from the original pop-up to open a new window. The results should be submitted back to the original browser window that invokes the first pop-up.

I've accomplished this with Mozilla and IE8, but want to make my implementation backwards compatible with other Internet Explorer versions.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
<base target="_self" />
```

Comment: You need to add a new line before the HTML to get the code block to render in your answer, it's too trivial an edit for me to do.

Comment: Hi mathhew... can you please tell me where i should exactly add this code <base target="_self"/>....